# URI field in a ICS file not recognized by Exchange

Tags: php, calendar, exchange-server, icalendar

Im trying to create an "Add to Outlook" button to our website's event app. I am using PHP to create a .ics file which works but I get this message when trying to add to our company's Exchange server, in iCal:

> Some information in your event will be saved to a different field. Do
>   you want to continue?Some of the fields in your original event aren't
>   available in Exchange...

The field that isnt being added is the URI one.

In Outlook the URI field doesnt  show up either, but without a warning. When I add it to a non-Exchange calendar it does show up.

Is this just a setting I have to change in our  Exchange server or is the URI field not recognized?

Comment: Should your URI be a UID field?

Comment: No, the URL property is a standard property (see [RFC 5545 Sect 3.8.4.6](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545.html#section-3.8.4.6)).  This just appears to be Exchange being rubbish -- have MS not _heard_ of standards, or are they only for the Little People?!

Answer (score 0):

Exchange does not support the URL field in ICS files. Just add the URL to the description field.

Answer (score -1):

I suspect your URI should be a UID field/property?   as in:
UID:19970901T130000Z-123401@example.com

The 19970901T130000Z-123401@example.com is a URI, but the property is the UID.

Check the spec: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.8.4.7.
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.3.13

A uri is a 'value' that can appear in many other fields.

Comment: URI is not UID property

Comment: IN ics (RFC5545) terms, a URI is a property, NOT a field in itself.  Therefore if your URI is not a property, then it is not part of the ics spec, it is unlikely to be treated as you expect by applications that receive ICS files.